# Rails4 polymorphic relationship on a certain type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a polymorphic relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
end
```

with

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end
```

I would like to add a `has_one :user` and a `has_one :group` relationship to my `Address` model if exists.

With Rails3, it worked doing:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, conditions: ['owner_type = ?', 'User']
  belongs_to :group, conditions: ['owner_type = ?', 'Group']
end
```

But now that conditions are gone in Rails4, I don't know how I can handle this.

I tried:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, -> {user_owner}, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  scope :user_owner, where(owner_type: 'User')
end
```

but it won't work as the scope is searched in the `User` model and I get a `user.owner_type does not exist` error.

At the end, I would like to being able to write for instance: `Address.joins(:user).where(whatever: true)`

Comment: Does it work if you set the condition directly instead of in the scope? i.e. `has_one :user, -> {where(owner_type: 'User')}`. Or by passing a lambda to the scope, i.e. `scope :user_owner,  -> { where(owner_type: 'User') } `?

Comment: No. The `where(owner_type: 'User')` is tried to be applied to the `User` model generating a `user.owner_type does not exist` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`has_one` is not the right approach, since the address `belongs_to` the `owner` and `has_one` expects the foreign_key to be in the association table.

If I understand correctly, you want `address.user` to return a user instance if the owner is a `User` otherwise to return `nil` (and the opposite for `address.group`). If that's the case, you can just create a simple method for that:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true

  def user
    owner_type == "User" ? self.owner : nil
  end

  def group
    owner_type == "Group" ? self.owner : nil
  end

  #these may create some confusion, but they will only be used with joins
  #maybe wrap them in their own Concern to have all the code in one 
  #location to make it clear for other team members

  #user_for_join will return the wrong association is address.owner_type != "User"
  belongs_to :user_for_join, foreign_key: :owner_id, class_name: User

  #group_for_join will return the wrong association is address.owner_type != "Group"
  belongs_to :group_for_join, foreign_key: :owner_id, class_name: Group

 def self.address_with_users
   #instead of calling Address.joins(:user), you now call Address.address_with_users
   self.where(owner_type: "User").joins(:user_for_join)
 end

 def self.address_with_groups
   self.where(owner_type: "Group").joins(:group_for_join)
 end


end
```

Comment: You understand correctly but your solution is not an ActiveRecord one. Eg. I would like to query `Address.joins(:user).where(whatever: true)` which I can't with your solution. You are right about the `has_one` though, it should be `belongs_to` instead.

Comment: I updated my answer to work with `joins`. Note that you can use `includes` to work with polymorphic association, i.e. `Association.where(owner_type: "User").includes(:owner)`

Answer (score 0):

[Rails Test code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f18ea14c893cb5c9f04d4fda9661126758332b5/activerecord/test/models/sponsor.rb) has an example where they use a lambda

```
belongs_to :user_with_conditions, -> { where :owner_type => 'User'}, :polymorphic => true,
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The `where(owner_type: 'User')` is tried to be applied to the `User` model generating a `user.owner_type does not exist` error. In the Rails Test code example, the `where(name: 'Ernie')` is applied to the `User`.